# Time and space complexity of these codes

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

I just learned about time and space complexity and I dont think I am really grasping them. I will put up some codes would would ask kindly if some of you could tell me their time and space complexity and how you decide them.

**Code 1**

```
public static int nmKomplex(int n, int m){
     int sum = 0;
     for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
       for(int j = 1; j < m; i++)
         sum += i * j;
     return sum;
}
```

**Code 2**

```
public static void Schleife3(int n){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      for(int j = 1; j<= n; j++)
         sum += i * j;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
       sum += i
}
```

Comment: Please don't take pictures of text. Just include the original text into the question

Comment: @JamesZ I endup expanding them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First code:

```
public static int nmKomplex(int n, int m){
     int sum = 0;
     for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
       for(int j = 1; j < m; i++)
         sum += i * j;
     return sum;
}
```

**TL:DR** Time Complexity `O(n * m)` | Space Complexity `O(1)`

A loop that goes from `i = 1` to `n` times another loop that goes from `j=1` to `m`. For `n > 1`, the first loop performs `(n - 1)` iterations, times the second loop which performs `(m - 1)` iterations. Hence, the double loop executes `nm - n - m + 1` iterations, which can be represented by a time complexity of  `O(n * m)`.

The space complexity is `O(1)` (*i.e.,* constant) since an increase in either the `n` and `m` values does not reflect in an increase of the space used.

Second code:

```
public static void Schleife3(int n){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      for(int j = 1; j<= n; j++)
         sum += i * j;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
       sum += i
}
```

**TL:DR** Time Complexity `O(n^2)` | Space Complexity `O(1)`

For n > 1, the first loop performance `n` iterations times the second loop which also performances  `n` iterations plus the third loop which also performance `n` iterations. Therefore, time complexity of n^2 + n, which can be represented by `O(n^2)`.

The space complexity is `O(1)` (*i.e.,* constant) since an increase in either the input `n` does not reflect in an increase of the space used.